# post-receive - Composer: Command Not Found in Shell Script - How to Fix PATH?

Tags: git, shell, composer-php, git-post-receive

I have been banging my head over this all day so I am breaking down in defeat and asking here for someone a little more versed in Shell Scripts than I am. I am attempting to write a post-receive script for a git repo on Inmotion Hosting.  Ideally this script is just to move the files to the site and then run `composer install` to build the vendor directory so it is not stored in the repo. My script should look like this based on all the examples I have seen.

```bash
#!/bin/sh 
git --work-tree=/home/[user]/[site] --git-dir=/home/[user]/[site].git checkout -f
composer install --working-dir=/home/[user]/[site]
```

The checkout portion works, but it fails at the install line.

I have read many other posts on possible issues, but composer is installed and runs globally from the cPanel terminal.  Users from the shell and terminal are the same as determined by using `whoami`.

This [post on laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/servers/composer-command-not-found-1?page=1) mentions that the PATH variable might be different.  I looked for my home bins and added them to the export by running `export PATH="/home/[user]/.local/bin:/home/[user]/bin:$PATH"` from my shell script, but still got a not found. This is where I am a little lost on what to do or how to fix the missing composer path.

Do I need to run `export PATH` each time with the script, and does anyone know what I should set it to? Should I even be attempting to change the PATH?  I can run my script fine through the cPanel terminal, but would really like to automate this.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: "it fails at the install line" - what does that mean? Is there any error message you could share? Also, is this a git problem or a Composer problem? I doubt that both technologies are related

Comment: @NicoHaase: he's cleverly hidden the error message in the title: it's `composer: command not found`.

Comment: @NicoHaase Yes, the error I am getting is `composer: command not found` but I am running the script on the post-receive hook of git.  I used `composer install --working-dir=/home/[user]/[site] -vvv > ~/composer.log 2>&1` to find the response when I ran the git push to the remote server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error might not be as obvious as the diagnostic message may be read by the user.

1. locate the absolute path of the `composer` command referenced in your original script. note it as `<absolute-path-to-composer>`.
2. locate the absolute path of the `php` cli SAPI binary on that system. note it as `<absolute-path-to-php>`.
3. invoke `php` (not `composer`) and tell it to load composer:

   ```
   <absolute-path-to-php> -f <absolute-path-to-composer> -- --working-dir==/home/[user]/[site]
   ```

Rationale: If the `composer` command actually exists but not the executable for it (`php` and `/usr/bin/env`) it will still error. To reliably execute composer in an unattended install, make the configuration explicit. `$PATH` etc. is convenience for interactive shell use - which is not the case here, the deployment script runs non-interactive.

---

Additionally, the script may be easier to maintain by cd-ing into the directory first and then use relative paths.

Then for any of the commands that are used by their basename (utility names), exit unsuccessful if `hash(1)` reports those missing.

Further, run Composer non-interactive (`-n`).

```
#! /bin/sh

cd /home/[user]/[site] || exit 1

hash -r
hash git || exit 1

git --work-tree=. --git-dir=../[site].git checkout -f

<absolute-path-to-php> -f <absolute-path-to-composer> -- -n install
```

---

Further on if you still have fun, do the operation in a temporary directory - not the site-root and when done `rsync(1)` into the target location.

Rationale is to separate the git checkout and composer install from the file operations within the site-directory. it will minimize issues on transaction failures (site broken but can't recover as deployment has issues).

Comment: That solved it! Final issue was the correct path to composer and it didn't need the `-- composer` text and didn't need the full php path. Final line looks like this `php /opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer -n install`. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes, that is an error in the answer. Thanks for commenting back, updated. The full paths are instructed b/c this is the failsafe way (get it working). The alternative is to safeguard (assert) the preconditions: `hash git php composer` - in your case `composer` did break only, `$PATH` modification might have done it (toreks answer is not wrong) for composer already. Commonly for the non-PATH commands, one creates a variable on top of script so that the paths can be easily configured / are visible at the top.

Answer (score 1):

The instructions in the post you've linked are correct up to a point: you must set (and preferably also `export`) `PATH`.  The likely problems are:

- there's a typo in what you tried;
- the use of `$HOME` and/or the rest of the path here is incorrect; and/or
- you've put the `export PATH=...` command in the wrong place.

The script should read:

```bash
#! /bin/sh
export PATH="[edit this part]:$PATH"
git --work-tree=/home/[user]/[site] --git-dir=/home/[user]/[site].git checkout -f
composer install --working-dir==/home/[user]/[site]
```

(where I've used your [square bracket] syntax to indicate that something goes there, but I don't know what).

Given that `composer` works from some other environment(s), start up a shell where it does work, and run `type composer`.  This will tell you *where* the composer binary is; that needs to be on `$PATH` after the `export`.

Check carefully for typos, including an invisible character in the command that resembles `composer`.  Invisible characters are of course hard to see: you need something that will display them, despite them being invisible.  (I'm fond of the BSD `vis` command for this, but you might not have that one.)

Comment: Thank you for the help. It may be the export being in the wrong spot.  It was not the first line in the code when I tried it. I will check when I get home. They have the port blocked where I am currently at.  Should be good on invisible characters, didn't see any extra ones in there.  On the last line of code, should their be a return after it, or should it end exactly where the last command ends?

Comment: Shell scripts can exit by just "falling off the end"; there's no need for "return" unless the shell script is intended to be run by `source` (`.`) (and in that case the rules get a little messy). You can explicitly `exit <status>`, e.g., `exit 0` for success, `exit 1` for generic failure, and if you don't call exit, or use `exit` with no argument, you exit with the status of the last command run.